# Which element in webrtc API stat refer to incoming bit rate

Tags: api, webrtc, dump, bitrate

I am trying to find any element  refer to IncomingBitrate  in  webrtc dump file .

Where I can find the incoming bitrate in webrtc-internals?

Also, How I can calculate incoming bitrate from webrtc stats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `webrtc-internals` check the active connection -- it's printed in bold. Usually it is `Conn-Audio-1-0`. There are two fields `bytesSent` and `bytesReceived` which will allow you to calculate the bitrate. Also check the constraints + stats demo for an actual example: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/constraints/

In `getStats`, iterate the reports until you find one of kind `googCandidatePair` with `.stat('googActiveConnection') === 'true'`. That is giving you the same information as `webrtc-internals`. If you want per-track/stream values, reports of type ssrc have `bytesSent` or `bytesReceived`, depending on whether they are sent or received.

Then calculate the bitrate by dividing the bytes sent/received by the time difference between the `getStats` calls.

Comment: is there any programmatic way by which we can get this info ?

Comment: see the sample (I updated the link) which uses the getStats API